# How to get the Place type from its coordinates (lat,longt) in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

how can i get  place type from its coordinates latitude ,longitude ?

when i read below url, it can be done. but here i could not pass coordinates as input (for variable name feature). Please anyone guide me how to do.

https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/custom-markers

```
var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
var icons = {
  parking: {
    icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
  },
  library: {
    icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
  },
  info: {
    icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
  }
};

function addMarker(feature) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: feature.position,
    icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
    map: map
  });
}
```

my requirement is to show coordinate in google with its own icon.It means that, if coordinates belongs to hospital then i should show hospital icon....like in this way.

so if i get to know place type from its coordinate then i think it can be done.

1. Also can any one please give me the mapping for Place type and its image.

Thanks...

Comment: Where does "feature" come from (in "addMarker(feature){..."), in the source of [that tutorial](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/js/markers) there is a array of features which contains those.

Comment: Plz read the URL and advise me. https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/custom-markers. I got to know the code from it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can really do this.

I don't know whether it is  best solution or not. If you have co-ordinate (latitude, longitude) then pass these co-ordinate to this GOOGLE PALCE API with your own API KEY.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

**API KEY IS YOUR OWN GOOGLE PLACE API KEY**

just look  this json response :-

```
{
  "html_attributions" : [
  "Listings by \u003ca href=\"http://www.yellowpages.com.au/\"\u003eYellow      Pages\u003c/a\u003e"
  ],
"results" : [
  {
     "formatted_address" : "529 Kent Street, Sydney NSW, Australia",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -33.8750460,
           "lng" : 151.2052720
        }
     },
     "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
     "id" : "827f1ac561d72ec25897df088199315f7cbbc8ed",
     "name" : "Tetsuya's",
     "rating" : 4.30,
     "reference" : "CnRmAAAAmmm3dlSVT3E7rIvwQ0lHBA4sayvxWEc4nZaXSSjRtfKRGoYnfr3d5AvQGk4e0u3oOErXsIJwtd3Wck1Onyw6pCzr8swW4E7dZ6wP4dV6AsXPvodwdVyqHgyGE_K8DqSp5McW_nFcci_-1jXb5Phv-RIQTzv5BjIGS0ufgTslfC6dqBoU7tw8NKUDHg28bPJlL0vGVWVgbTg",
     "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ]
  },
  {
     "formatted_address" : "Upper Level, Overseas Passenger Terminal/5 Hickson Road, The Rocks NSW, Australia",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -33.8583790,
           "lng" : 151.2100270
        }
     },
     "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/cafe-71.png",
     "id" : "f181b872b9bc680c8966df3e5770ae9839115440",
     "name" : "Quay",
     "rating" : 4.10,
     "reference" : "CnRiAAAADmPDOkn3znv_fX78Ma6X5_t7caEGNdSWnpwMIdDNZkLpVKPnQJXP1ghlySO-ixqs28UtDmJaOlCHn18pxpj7UQjRzR4Kmye6Gijoqoox9bpkaCAJatbJGZEIIUwRbTNIE_L2jGo5BDqiosqU2F5QdBIQbXKrvfQuo6rmu8285j7bDBoUrGrN4r6XQ-PVm260PFt5kwc3EfY",
     "types" : [ "cafe", "bar", "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ]
  },
  {
     "formatted_address" : "107 George Street, The Rocks NSW, Australia",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -33.8597750,
           "lng" : 151.2085920
        }
     },
     "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
     "id" : "7beacea28938ae42bcac04faf79a607bf84409e6",
     "name" : "Rockpool",
     "rating" : 4.0,
     "reference" : "CnRlAAAAVK4Ek78r9yHV56I-zbaTxo9YiroCbTlel-ZRj2i6yGAkLwNMm_flMhCl3j8ZHN-jJyG1TvKqBBnKQS2z4Tceu-1kZupZ1HSo5JWRBKd7qt2vKgT8VauiEBQL-zJiKVzSy5rFfilKDLSiLusmdi88ThIQqqj6hKHn5awdj6C4f59ifRoUg67KlbpuGuuW7S1tAH_EyBl6KE4",
     "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ]
  },
  {
     "formatted_address" : "483 George Street, Sydney NSW, Australia",
     "events" : [
        {
          "event_id" : "7lH_gK1GphU",
          "summary" : "Google Maps Developer Meetup: Rockin' out with the Places API",
          "url" : "https://developers.google.com/places"
        }
      ],
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -33.8731950,
           "lng" : 151.2063380
        }
     },
     "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/civic_building-71.png",
     "id" : "017049cb4e82412aaf0efbde890e82b7f2987c16",
     "name" : "Chinatown Sydney",
     "rating" : 4.0,
     "reference" : "CnRuAAAAsLNeRQtKD7TEUXWG6gYD7ByOVKjQE61GSyeGZrX-pOPVps2BaLBlH0zBHlrVU9DKhsuXra075loWmZUCbczKDPdCaP9FVJXB2NsZ1q7188pqRFik58S9Z1lcWjyVoVqvdUUt9bDMLqxVT4ENmolbgBIQ9Wy0sgDy0BgWyg5kfPMHCxoUOvmhfKC-lTefXGgnsRqEQwn8M0I",
     "types" : [
        "city_hall",
        "park",
        "restaurant",
        "doctor",
        "train_station",
        "local_government_office",
        "food",
        "health",
        "establishment"
     ]
  }
   ], 
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

then get the icon of your place :-

```
"icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/cafe-71.png",
```

for more read the  [original link](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchResponses)